# How to interpret the within, between and overall R2 of a random effects model?

Tags: stata, random-effects-model, r-squared

How would you explain in easy-to-understand language what the difference is between the within, between and overall R-squared of a Random Effects panel data model? How are those values to be interpreted?

[image: Example of Stata-output]

Comment: please indicate major components/elements eyc. of your model ?

Comment: It is a first-difference panel data model (three years, grouped by region). I added an image of the Stata-output for clarification of what I am trying to understand better.

Comment: You may kindly indicate proper and complete output sheet and  p values as well ss t valuea and regression coefficients .